# How would I include multiple criteria in an if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, compiler-errors

I want to have multiple options inside an if statement such as `if (Option1.equalsIgnoreCase("x" && "y"))`. But when I actually try to write the above said code, it wont work. My objective is for the `if` statement to work if one out of 2 or 3 criteria are met.

Comment: `Option1.equalsIgnoreCase("x") && Option1.equalsIgnoreCase("y")`

Comment: use the || "or" operator instead of the && "and" this way it will see if any option is true rather than them both having to be true

Comment: I think you are looking for `Regex`.

Comment: It won't *compile* for you. Be accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do something if Option1 is "x" or "y" use the following:

```
if (Option1.equalsIgnoreCase("x") || Option1.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
    //do stuff
}
```

|| means OR, while && means AND. If you would use && Option1 would have to be x and y at the same time, which isn't possible.

Comment: Thank you!! You really helped a lot!

Comment: Don't forget to accept or vote an answer, @TheChosenSnail

Answer (score 0):

You have to split your checks in different checks, you can't combine them in just a single check.

Example of logical AND,below code will return true if **optional1** is equal to both `X` and `Y`(which it can't). Note I used `&&` operator, which is called **AND** operator :-

```
if(Option1.equalsIgnoreCase("x") && Option1.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
 // do something
}
```

Example of logical OR. below code will return true if **optional1** is equal to either `X` or `Y`. Note I used `||`, which is called **OR** operator.

```
if(Option1.equalsIgnoreCase("x") || Option1.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
     // do something
    }
```

Combination of OR and logical AND operator.(this will return true if optional1 is either equal to X or Y and option2 is equal to Z. )

```
 if((Option1.equalsIgnoreCase("x") || Option1.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) && Option2.equalsIgnoreCase("Z")){
         // do something
        }
```

. like this can combine multiple conditions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression

```
option1.matches("[xXyY]")
```

Which says is the string any case of  x or y?

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, Java doesn't do conditions like that.

You have to separate the check into two clauses in your if statement, like:

```
if ("x".equalsIgnoreCase(Option1) || "y".equalsIgnoreCase(Option2) {
   ....
}
```

Noticed that I used `||` (or OR) not `&&` (AND) as well, as if we use `&&`, it will never be true (a string can never be BOTH "x" and "y").

More info in [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html).

Comment: Why 'unfortunately'?

Comment: Because we can't do it that way? :)